# Error in ConnectionFactory in rabbitmq

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I used RabbitMQ in my java application . I used amqp-client3.1.3.jar. But getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory while deploying my code in jboss. How to resolve?

```
public class Exapmle {
    static Connection connection = null;
    static Channel channel = null;
    static ConnectionFactory factory = null;
    private Example() {
        try {
            factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            //--code goes here---//
        }
```

I had written the same code in ejb which is scheduled and deployed in wildfly. I saw the resolution of adding the dependency to jboss setup. How should i do this?

Comment: Your jar file isn't on the runtime classpath.

Comment: @ Kayaman Thanks, i added jar in my jboss setup. Now its working.